# Writing lines to .txt file c++

Tags: c++, fileoutputstream

For all you programmers out there! I'm trying to figure out why my program won't work. I'm stumped! I'm trying to write a program to open a text file named "CSC2134.TXT" for output, then accept lines of text from the console and write the lines of text to the file and use any empty string to end the program. Here's what I have:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <cstring> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
 char str[80]; 

 ofstream file1; 
 file1.open("CSC2134.txt"); 

 if (file1 == 0) 
  { 
    cout << "error opening CSC2134.txt" << endl; 
    return 1; 
  } 
 else 
  { 
   file1 << "Enter some text:\n"; 
   while(strlen(str) != '\n') 
    { 
     file1 << cin.getline(str,80); 

     if(strlen(str) == 0) 
     break; 
    } 
   file1.close(); 
  } 

  return 0; 
}
```

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting the error message.

Comment: *What* error message?

Comment: Error opening the file

Comment: What development tool are you using, and are you running the program though that tool? Often where the program is being run from is not where you expect or where you put the file. Eclipse, for example, looks for files without a [fully qualified (complete) path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) in the root project folder, not in the same folder as the executable.

Comment: Check to see what permissions you have on the directory that the program resides in.  Issue a `ls -lad .` command from that directory. If you don't have write permissions on that directory, then your program can't open the file. You  will need to give yourself write permissions to that directory

Comment: I'm using codeblocks but because I have Norton (lol tends to consider my program a 'high risk virus') I use cpp.sh to compile it (if Norton doesn't block it on codeblocks).

Comment: Bummer. Code::blocks I don't know worth beans and can't advise on.

Comment: But you can find where the program is looking for your file with [GetCurrentDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934(v=vs.85).aspx) under windows or [getcwd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) on a POSIX-compliant system.

Comment: You should be able to configure Norton to ignore a folder, then do all of your programming work within subfolders of that folder.

Comment: And you may be able to get a better error message from [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) or [perror](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/perror)

Comment: Thank you. Would I use that in a different program?  Sorry, I'm not trying to be difficult.  This is my first time being introduced to most of these terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    ofstream myfile("CSC2134.txt");

    if(myfile.is_open())
    {
        string str;
        do{
            getline(cin, str);
            myfile<<str<< endl;
        }while(str!="");
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cerr<<"Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm. Is it a compilation error? Does the compiler say anything?

Comment: Windows 7 Home  Premium but I upgraded to Windows 10 Home.  I appreciate you for all the help

Comment: :) I have the same operation system, and my solution works on it. First we have to find out whether my code is wrong or you make some mistakes? There are another two answers. Do any of them work?

Comment: Hmm... Now when I tried your program I get nothing at all, just return 0.  It doesn't allow me to input text

Comment: Aha!!!!! You shoul open the CSC2134.txt. It will contain the result you are looking for. :) Please tell me, if it works!

Comment: I don't see the CSC2134.txt file

Comment: Yes.  I even search C: for it.  Nothing.  When I try to execute it in Codeblocks on my laptop, Norton blocks it every time.  I've tried to exclude it from the scan but it still blocks it.  So I've been trying to use cpp.sh to compile and execute it.  I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: It works!!! Norton was interrupting the executing process.  Thank you so much for your time and patience!!!

Comment: Your welcome! It is very difficult at the begining. So we are happy now. :)

Comment: :D It really is.  Thank you so so very much! Yes I am!  Now I can sleep

Comment: May be the folder security settings are wrong. It is just a tip

Answer (score 2):

You have a few mistakes:

You  are outputting the "enter some text" to the file instead of to cout.

You are not looping in the correct manner, so as to only exit the app if a user's input is empty string.

Here's a corrected version:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <cstring> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
 char str[80]; 

 fstream file1; 
 file1.open("CSC2134.txt"); 

 if (!file1.is_open()) 
  { 
    cout << "error opening CSC2134.txt" << endl; 
    return 1; 
  } 
 else 
  { 
   std::cout<< "Enter some text:\n"; 

   cin.getline(str,80);
   while((strlen(str) != 0) ) 
    { 

     file1 << str;
     cin.getline(str,80);

    } 
   file1.close(); 
  } 

  return 0; 
}
```

**Update:**

Run this instead, and tell me what the output is when you run your program:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <cstring> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
 char str[80]; 

 ofstream file1; 

 file1.exceptions ( ifstream::failbit | ifstream::badbit );
 try {
  file1.open("CSC2134.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::binary);
 }
 catch (ifstream::failure e) {
    cout << "Exception opening/reading file"<< e.what();
  }

 if (!file1.is_open()) 
  { 
    cout << "error opening CSC2134.txt" << endl; 
    return 1; 
  } 
 else 
  { 
   std::cout<< "Enter some text:\n"; 

   cin.getline(str,80);
   while((strlen(str) != 0) ) 
    { 

     file1 << str;
     cin.getline(str,80);

    } 
   file1.close(); 
  } 

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Suggest using `while ( cin.getline(str,80) && strlen(str) != 0 )`. Otherwise, the `while` loop might get into an infinite loop.

Comment: For some reason, I'm still getting the error message :'(

Comment: @3pic1namie6 : This could be because you don't have write permissions on the directory that the executable exists in.

Comment: How exactly would I go about doing that?

Comment: I appreciate you for all your help.  Sorry for being so difficult

Comment: Okay.  I found the directory.  Thank you. What next?

Comment: Says warning: \A \L and \T as unknown escape sequences. And even when I reverse all of the slashes, it still comes out with the error message

Comment: My bad, try this:   file1.open("C:\\Users\\<YourUsername>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\CSC2134.txt");

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your program worked!! It wouldn't execute correctly because of Norton.  Thank you so much again for your patience :D

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version with mistakes and ungood practices corrected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>     // EXIT_FAILURE
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto const filename = "CSC2134.txt";
    ofstream file1( filename );
    if( file1.fail() )
    {
        cerr << "!Error opening " << filename << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    string str;
    cout << "Enter some text, with a blank last line:\n";
    while( getline( cin, str ) && str != "" )
    {
        file1 << str << endl;
    }
}
```

Personally I would write `and` instead of `&&`, but a beginner can't be expected to configure compiler correctly to accept that. The problem is mainly with Visual C++. One can use a forced include of `<iso646.h>` to make it accept standard `and`, `or` and `not`.

Tip: I used the free **AStyle** program to fix the indentation to something more clear to me.

Comment: My god man! You want your code to be readable? But what of job security? Security through obscurity, my good sir! Security through obscurity!

Comment: My instructor never introduced me to cerr or the std.lib, so like you said I'm a noob.  A total noob!  Thank you.